# creating tempfiles in a forvalue loop

Tags: stata

I have a dataset where I want to get the sample size for each race category by year and sector (occupation). My race variable name is wbho and the values are White (1), Black(2), Hispanic(3), Others(3). I wrote a forval loop to do this, but I can't save them as different tempfiles inside the loop (since the race variable name is the same for each collapse result). In the end, I want to append the 4 tempfiles. How can I do that? Here is my loop:

```
forval i=1/4 {
use ${data}wbho.dta, clear
gcollapse (count) wbho if wbho==`i', by (year docc03)
}
```

After each tempfile is saved, I was going to append like this:

```
 use `part1', clear 
append using `part2'
append using `part3'
append using `part4'
tempfile overall
save `overall'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow why you're looping in the first place.

```
use ${data}wbho.dta, clear
contract wbho year docc03
```

Comment: amazing! I wasn't familiar with the contract command . What if I was doing the collapse(mean)? Would I need the forvalue loop?

Comment: Please edit your question to make specific what kind of mean you want.

Comment: I use collapse(mean) to calculate the share of each demographic (white, black, etc) by year and occupation. I modified the above loop to do this. I was just wondering if there was a simpler way to do this.

Comment: `contract` has a `percent()` option.